# What is the double hyphen in scss?

Tags: sass

I'm new to SASS and cam across something I don't understand. In one of my projects I see a developer setup some inheritance like this:

```
&--outline,
&--outline:focus,
&--outline:active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: color($colors, navia_orange, base);
    border: 1px solid color($colors, navia_orange, base);

    &.button-md, &.button-ios {
        box-shadow: unset;

        &.activated {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: color($colors, navia_orange, base);
            border: 1px solid color($colors, navia_orange, base);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the '&' is a way of inserting the parent selector. But what does the '--' do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`&` refers to parent, so this is meaningless, unless nested. But imagine what happens when it is nested inside, e.g. `.button`:

```
.button {
  &--outline {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

produces a derived class name:

```
.button--outline {
  /* ... */
}
```

that would indicate e.g. an element like this:

```
<button class="button--outline">...</button>
```

tl;dr: `--` is absolutely nothing special. It doesn't *do* anything. It just gets concatenated.

Comment: This is a great answer, except I disagree about "is absolutely nothing special".  I can see how, possibly based on your team's scss preferences and/or scss standards it has no value, and maybe even on some personal preferences.  That said, if you're a shorthander that still wants to keep things legible, this could prove a valuable rule/pattern/practice in your team's scss standards.

Your answer about it's explanation was spot on, I for sure gave it a vote.

Comment: @anothercoder I meant it has no meaning according to SCSS grammar (as opposed to `&`, which has a defined semantics in SCSS), just like `// TODO` comment has no meaning in JavaScript. It was meant to answer the literal question in the title: "What is the double hyphen in scss?". It better have meaning to the _programmer_, else no-one would be using it.

Answer (score 12):

Double hyphen is a modifier used in [BEM (Block, Element, Modifier)](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#modifier) methodology, which helps you organize your stylesheet. It has nothing to do with Sass.

In this case it takes advantage of Sass syntax, which lets you write nested selectors, and that's why it is written this way. The other way it would be looking like: `.block-or-element--outline {}`.